# Windows file copy using autohotkey script

Tags: dll, autohotkey, system-calls, file-copying

I am trying to over come the non responsive nature of file copy implemented using [autohotkey](https://autohotkey.com).

I am trying to do this though [Dllcall()](https://lexikos.github.io/v1/docs/commands/DllCall.htm) to [CopyFileEx()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363852(v=vs.85).aspx) function in Kernel32.dll.

Following is the C++ interface of CopyFileEx() function, but i have no idea how to make it work with autohotkey script.

> BOOL WINAPI CopyFileEx(
>
> *In*      LPCTSTR lpExistingFileName,
>
> *In*      LPCTSTR lpNewFileName,
>
> _In_opt_  LPPROGRESS_ROUTINE lpProgressRoutine,
>
> _In_opt_  LPVOID lpData,
>
> _In_opt_  LPBOOL pbCancel,
>
> *In*      DWORD dwCopyFlags
>
> );

Thanks for the help in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/20790-copyfileex-dllcall-and-registercallback

> file1:="movetest.exe" file2:="movetest2.exe"
>
> address :=registercallback("update")
>   dllcall("CopyFileEx",str,file1,str,file2,Uint,address,Uint,0,int,0,int,0)
>
> return
>
> Esc::ExitApp
>   update(var1lo,var1hi,var2lo,var2hi,var3lo,var3hi,var4lo,var4hi,var5,var6,var7,var8,var9){
>   progress,% (var2lo/var1lo) * 100,,% (var2lo/var1lo) * 100 " %",copying
>   file   return 0 }

The link above is exactly what i needed. Someone on the autohotkey forum posted the answer, thought I would also share it with you guys.